# Ajax-HTML for doing simple calculator

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

**Question:**  Implement a basic calculator application by getting the two operands and one operator from the form in a textbox. Also have a button called result and when the same is clicked display the result. Only the result part of the page must change

**My code is here, but its not at all working, please help me in displaying the output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
function showResult(id,url)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    var val1=document.form1.value1.value;
    var valu1=parseInt(val1);
    var val2=document.form1.value2.value;
    var valu2=parseInt(val2);
    var val3=document.form1.operator.value;
    var result;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    if("+"==val3)
    {
    result=valu1+valu2;
    //alert(result);
    }
else if("-".equals(val3))
    {
    result=val1-val2;
    }
else if("*".equals(val3))
{
result=val1*val2;
}
else if("/".equals(val3))
{
result=val1/val2;
}
else
    {
    alert("choose oly +,-,*,/");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name=form1 method=get>
<input type=text name="value1">
<input type=text name="value2">
<input type=text name="operator">
<input type=button value="Result" name=result onClick="showResult('ajaxDiv','BasicCalc.html')">
</form>
<div id="ajaxdiv"> Your Result soon will be display here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which part of your code are you having trouble with?

Comment: You are trying to solve problem, you should not have had in first place - why do you need AJAX, to process math? JavaScript has built-in `Math` library and simple operators, that can handle almost any calculator function.

Comment: this is just for practice, how we can upadet only part of page using Ajax with out reloading whole page....